# C++ Iterator for std::set or std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Let's say I have this:

```
struct HoldStuff {
  std::vector<StuffItem> items;
  std::set<StuffItem, StuffItemComparator> sorted_items;
}
```

Now, during a refactor, I may have stuff in `items` or I may have it in `sorted_items`, but regardless I want to do the same thing with each item. I want to do something like this:

```
HoldStuff holder;  // assume it was filled earlier
auto iter = holder.items.empty() ? holder.sorted_items.begin() :
                                   holder.items.begin();
auto iter_end = holder.items.empty() ? holder.sorted_items.end() :
                                       holder.items.end();
for (; iter != iter_end; ++iter) {
    auto& item = *iter;
    // Do stuff
}
```

When I go to compile this, I get errors complaining about incompatible operand types. Surely this is possible, no?

Comment: You need to define some kind of `any_iterator` (or use an existing implementation, see [here](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- use type-erasure to get a runtime polymorphism on the iterator (`any_range` or `any_iterator`)
- delegate `do_stuff` to a function template that takes any kind of iterator

Here is an illustration with code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

template<typename Iterator>
void do_stuff(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> items;
  std::set<int> sorted_items;
  // first option
  typedef boost::any_range<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag, int&, std::ptrdiff_t> my_any_range;
  my_any_range r;
  if(items.empty())
    r = my_any_range(sorted_items);
  else
    r = my_any_range(items);
  for (auto& x : r) {
    std::cout << x << " ";
  }

  // second option
  // this could also be a lambda and std::for_each
  if(items.empty())
    do_stuff(sorted_items.begin(), sorted_items.end());
  else
    do_stuff(items.begin(), items.end());
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are correct: **auto** keyword works during compilation. In an easy way, it just deduces the type of assignment and uses this **real** type. But decision if it's vector's iterator or set's is made in runtime. So type can not be deduced.
As SergeyA said, I'm wrong here, compiler fail on ?: operator, before auto. But the reason is still the same - it has no idea which type to use for the result.

You should probably use some more generic iterator type + polymorphism, or you can make this function parameterized on type , where T is an iterator type. I would prefer to do it this way:

```
template<class T> do_stuff(T &c) {  for (auto &el : c) { /*Whatever*/ } }

...

if (!items.empty()) {
    do_stuff(items);
} else if (!sorted_items.empty()) {
    do_stuff(sorted_items);
}
```

P.S.: It's a conception, I didn't test the code.

Comment: The actual issue is not with auto. It is with different types on sides of ternary operator. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both sides of the ternary operator need to have the same type. In your case, they are different - std::vector<>::iterator and std::set<> iterator. A suitable solution seems to be some sort of a an iterator wrapper, which returns one or another depending on the initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

`auto` means the **compiler** will deduce the type of what follows, at compilation time.

The return type of the ternary conditional operator in this case is what follows the question mark, so it is `std::set<StuffItem, StuffItemComparator>::iterator` and the compiler tries to cast what follows the column (`std::vector<StuffItem>::iterator`) to this incompatible type, hence the compiler error.

What you can do is make your item processing code generic, like so:

```
auto doStuff = [] (StuffItem& item) {
  // do stuff with item...
};
if( holder.items.size() )
  for_each( holder.items.begin(), holder.items.end(), doStuff );
else if( holder.sorted_items.size() )
  for_each( holder.sorted_items.begin(), holder.sorted_items.end(), doStuff );
```